# Operadores de Bits en python

Tags: python

Teniendo en cuenta que los operadores de bits en python (&,|,~, etc..) se emplean para precisamente hacer operaciones de manera muy similar a como lo haria una CPU, mi duda radica en lo siguiente: sabiendo que, en las operaciones con conjuntos (sets para los amigos) se hacen cosas totalmente distintas a nivel de RAM, por que se utilizan los mismos operadores?.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a ,por ejemplo, porqué una union de sets se puede hacer con el operador `|` (`or`)?

Comment: No, por que se emplean los mismos operadores si se hace algo totalmente distinto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías hacerte la misma pregunta respecto al operador `+` y otros. ¿Cómo es que se usa el mismo operador para hacer `1+1` que para hacer  `"1"+"1"`, si lo que hacen es completamente distinto? ¿Cómo es que el operador `/` puede usarse tanto para dividir números, como para separar componentes de una ruta si usas el módulo `pathlib`? etc...

La explicación pragmática sería: porque el lenguaje lo permite y ayuda a mejorar la legibilidad en muchos casos. El operador `+`  (así como los operadores `/`, `|`, `&` etc) se pueden redefinir para que hagan lo que quieras y operen con cualquier tipo de datos que tú definas. Esto puede ser muy útil para implementar por ejemplo cálculo matricial (numpy, pandas) o en casos como la concatenación de cadenas o de rutas de `pathlib`. En el caso de los conjuntos hace el código más compacto.

Puedes objetar que no obstante el uso de esos operadores es "contraintuitivo" ¿qué tiene que ver una operación OR a nivel de bits con la unión de conjuntos?

Sin embargo, en el caso de los conjuntos las operaciones `&` y `|` no son tan *radicalmente* diferentes como parece a primera vista de esas mismas operaciones a nivel de bits. De hecho, en un cierto sentido (que ejemplificaré seguidamente), hacen lo mismo.

#### Ejemplo

Imagina que para representar un conjunto elegimos usar un *mapa de bits* (no es así como los representa Python, pero servirá para ilustrar mi punto). Esto es, tenemos un bit para representar a cada posible elemento de un conjunto, y si ese bit es 1 es que el elemento está en el conjunto, mientras que si es cero es que no está en el conjunto.

Así, por ejemplo, si nuestros posibles elementos fueran los números del 1 al 10, podríamos tener 10 bits. El primer bit representa al elemento 1, el siguiente al elemento 2, y así hasta que el último bit representaría al elemento 10.

Con esta representación el conjunto vacío `Z` sería `00000 00000` (diez ceros, pues los diez posibles elementos están ausentes). Un conjunto `A` que contenga al 1 y al 3 podría ser `10100 00000`. Un conjunto `B` que contenga al 3, 4, 7 y 10 sería `00110 01001`.

```
     1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9 10
Z = |0|0|0|0|0| 0|0|0|0|0|   Conjunto vacío {}
A = |1|0|1|0|0| 0|0|0|0|0|   Conjunto {1,3}
B = |0|0|1|1|0| 0|1|0|0|1|   Conjunto {3,4,7,10}
```

Pues fíjate que las operaciones a nivel de bits dan el resultado deseado sobre estas representaciones de conjuntos!

- `A|B` a nivel de bits daría `10110 01001`, que es el resultado de esa unión de conjuntos, pues quedan presentes los elementos 1, 3, 4, 7 y 10
- `A&B` a nivel de bits daría `00100 00000`, y efectivamente eso representa al conjunto intersección, pues sólo contiene el 3.
- Funciona también con el conjunto vacío: `Z & A` sale `00000 00000`, mientras que `Z|A` sale `A`.

También puedes leerlo así: `A|B` es el conjunto de los elementos que están en A **o** en B. `A&B` es el conjunto de los elementos que están en A **Y** en B.

Y si te preguntas por qué no se decidió entonces usar las palabras `and` y `or` para esto, la respuesta es que estas palabras **no son operadores redefinibles**. Están reservadas exclusivamente para ser usadas en contextos booleanos.